# preg_match inside a preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm using the following preg_match to get the [title] tag of a webpage.

```
// get <title>
$search = "/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title>/i";
preg_match($search, $url_contents, $result);
$title = $result[1];
```

Now I want to search inside that [title] tag, so I wrote this:

```
// search for $keyword
$keyword_slash = "/". $keyword ."/";
preg_match_all($keyword_slash, $title, $result);
print_r($result); // just for testing
```

I've added $keyword_slash because else it gave me an error. Yet, this doesn't work. It always returns an empty array even though I know that $keyword is inside the [title].

Comment: What's in `$keyword`? Do an `echo $keyword_slash;` and update your question.

Comment: You may also want to [preg_quote()](http://php.net/preg_quote) `$keyword` in case it ever contains any metacharacters.  Also, add the case insensitive `i` modifier to that regex so case doesn't matter for the keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex first preg_match doesn't seem to be right. It should be:

```
$search = "~<title>([^<]*)</title>~i";
```

However I must remind you that extracting title using regex like this is **extremely error prone** and you should consider using DOM parser to get that.

**Update:** Here is the suggested DOM parsing for title of a page:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($content);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$title = $xpath->query("//head/title")->item(0)->nodeValue;
printf("title=[%s]\n", $title);
```

Comment: Replace `.*?` with `[^<]`. It's much more efficient.

Comment: The first works, but I'll take it that yours is more effective (i"ll google later!). However, updating it still gives a blank array.

Array ( [0] => Array ( ) )